# How to connect to MovieDB API webservice?

Tags: java, json, web-services, jakarta-ee, getjson

I am new to webservice and I am in the learning phase. Not much of the online content gives information about the use of MovieDB API webservice. Well for not I am just focusing on trying to get a movie information on the screen.

So the as per the [API](http://docs.themoviedb.apiary.io/) I am requesting the information and I am getting the JSON response when I paste http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=MYKEY in the browser.

I want to write a webservice using JAVA,SOAP to parse the JSON and fetch the required information. I tried using HttpURLConnection and then use BufferedReader but its not working.

Kindly suggest me some better options. Any links/blogs will be helpful.

This is the code snippet.

```
public class TestJSON {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=MYKEY/3/movie/550");
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setDoOutput(true);
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

        String input = "";

        OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
        os.write(input.getBytes());
        os.flush();

        if (con.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + con.getResponseCode());
        }

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));

        String output;
        System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
        while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(output);
        }

        con.disconnect();


    }
    catch(MalformedURLException m){
        System.out.println("Malformed URL");
    }
    catch(IOException ioe){
        System.out.println("IO exception");
    }


}
```

}

Thanks in advance.

Zingo

Comment: Never shy to share the code you have tried.

Comment: @JunedAhsan thanks I have my code now.

Comment: Can you mention the error/exception you are getting?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I am getting IO Exception... So I tried to debug my code and I found that the object con of HttpURLConnection has a response NULL. Where as when I try the link form browser there is some JSON response that I get.So there is some problem with the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to read the output from the url:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                          new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer html = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    html.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

Comment: I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 401

Comment: @Zingo You are getting that because your token/key  is not valid.

Comment: for security reasons I cannot provide the key. The key is valid and when I insert the actual key in the url and paste it in browser it works fine. So I think the key is not an issue. There seems to be some issue with the way I am accessing the service.

Comment: @Zingo I am not sure about the service. But 401 means unauthorized, so you may be missing to send some credentials as part of a required header. If you have documentation for the service, then try to find that info.

Comment: @JunedAhsan Even if the key is invalid, it doesn't through exceptions.Rather it should give

Comment: @JunedAhsan you were right there was some extra information next to the APIKEY... Well now I am getting 404!